# CoreText compile errors via DTCoreText

Tags: iphone, ios, core-text

In my first experience with CocoaPods I've run into a problem. I'm using CocoaPods on an existing project to install DTCoreText specifically for DTAttributedLabel. All goes smoothly and appears to work fine but the second I include DTCoreText.h I get multiple errors with the CoreText framework like the following:

```
CoreText.framework/Headers/CTRunDelegate.h:130:16: Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

 typedef struct
 {
     CFIndex                            version;
     CTRunDelegateDeallocateCallback    dealloc;
     CTRunDelegateGetAscentCallback getAscent;
     CTRunDelegateGetDescentCallback    getDescent;
     CTRunDelegateGetWidthCallback  getWidth;
 } CTRunDelegateCallbacks;


CoreText.framework/Headers/SFNTLayoutTypes.h:821:23: Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

struct LcarCaretTable {
   Fixed               version;
   UInt16              format;
   SFNTLookupTable     lookup;
 };
```

I created a single view project just to check my install technique and was able to use DTCoreText just fine.

- Is there a setting that I'm missing that could be causing this?  (Deployment target: 6.1, SDK 6.1)
- Perhaps a conflict with an existing library?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating a new project and installing all dependencies through Cocoapods. It appears the issue was related to a conflict.